# Save a Collection of objects to disk Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: vb.net

I have a collection of objects which also contain collections, and I would like to save them to a file and read later. This is Windows 10 UNIVERSAL app .net 4.5 and in VB

I've this, but it gives the error "Synchronous operations should not be performed on the UI thread.  Consider wrapping this method in Task.Run."}

```
 Public Sub SaveSpRules(FileName As String)
    Dim fs As New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Rule))
    Dim writer As New StreamWriter(fs)

        serializer.Serialize(writer, r)
   End Sub
```

Rule is class and the collection is called SpecialRulesCollection, this code does compile but doesn't work

Any help is gratefully received.  PLEASE note this for Windows 10 Universal app, I can't get BinaryWriter to compile as this isn't include in the Universal app.

Comment: I'm not familiar with vb but your error sounds pretty straight forward- either make your function async by adding the async keyword (can you do that in vb?), or put the code within a Task.Run (()=> {...code here...}). Not sure about the syntax where it comes to vb but hopefully this can be helpful at a pointer to the right direction at least.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Oyiwai I found the answer

Public Async Sub SaveSpRules(FileName As String, t As Object)

```
Dim myfile As StorageFile

myfile = Await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.dat", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)

Dim KnownTypeList As New List(Of Type)

KnownTypeList.Add(GetType(Rules))

KnownTypeList.Add(GetType(Rule))

Dim r As Streams.IRandomAccessStream

r = Await myfile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)

Using outStream As Streams.IOutputStream = r.GetOutputStreamAt(0)

Dim serializer As New DataContractSerializer(GetType(Rules), KnownTypeList)

serializer.WriteObject(outStream.AsStreamForWrite(), t)

Await outStream.FlushAsync()

outStream.Dispose()

r.Dispose()

End Using

End Sub

Public Async Sub ReadFile()

Dim t As New Collection(Of Rule)

Dim myfile As Stream

Dim r As New Rules

Dim KnownTypeList As New List(Of Type)

KnownTypeList.Add(GetType(Rules))

Dim serializer As New DataContractSerializer(GetType(Rules), KnownTypeList)

myfile = Await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("test.dat")

r = serializer.ReadObject(myfile)

End Sub
```